# cakephp 1.2 facebook login

Tags: php, facebook, cakephp-1.2

I have an CakePHP 1.2 Webapplication and I want to integrate a facebook login-button for non-registered users. I found a [CakePHP Plugin](https://github.com/webtechnick/CakePHP-Facebook-Plugin) but it doesn´t work with my old CakePHP version. Is there any other older Plugin for CakePHP 1.2

Comment: I think before implement Facebook Login into your app, you should first upgrade to the latest version of CakePHP. I dont think you will find help or support for a codebase that old.

Comment: I guess I will need 2 months for the upgrade because the application has more than 20000 lines of code -.-

Comment: It might be better! Just FYI, I have a CakePHP news site, that I want to upgrade to the latest version of Cake. I wanted to migrate, but since there were unfinished features I could not implement before, I decided to rewrite the entire site incorporating everything. It is being a pleasure, since I am really testing my Cake skills, but most importantly I am learning other things I had taken for grant. Best decision I made!. Based on the time I've taken, it should take me, altogether, about 100 hours programming hours to finish and have a robust system.

Answer (score 1):

Try implementing Facebook login without using that CakePHP plugin.